# querySelectorAll and multiple elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am currently trying to adapt [this demo](https://tympanus.net/Development/ShapeOverlays/index.html) for page transitions when you click on the links with the same class applied to them.

I am not sure how to adapt the following piece of code for all the elements that has the same class following the use of `querySelectorAll`. What do you think should be tweaked to make it work with `querySelectorAll` and multiple elements with the same class?

```
(function() {
  const elmHamburger = document.querySelector('.link-with-overlay');
  const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
  const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

  elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (overlay.isAnimating) {
      return false;
    }
    overlay.toggle();
    if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
      elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi');

    } else {
      elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not related to your main issue, however worth mentioning: if you care about performance for basic look ups (by classname only) there's [much faster](https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/25) option - [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: If you're looking for a method to query **all** matches, I'm guessing you're thinking of [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which is not the best candidate for that job (see my previous comment).

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look at `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow all the links to have an onclick event you'll need to iterate over the `NodeList` that the `querySelectorAll` method returns.

*NOTE: You cannot do `NodeList.forEach` in IE11 so you'd need to polyfill or convert it to a true JS array before iterating.*

```
(function() {
  const elmHamburgers = document.querySelectorAll('.link-with-overlay');
  const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
  const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

  const onHamburgerClick = function() {
    if (overlay.isAnimating) {
      return false;
    }
    overlay.toggle();
    if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
      this.classList.add('is-opened-navi');

    } else {
      this.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
    }
  };

  // Iterates over all of the elements matched with class .link-with-overlay and 
  // adds an onclick event listener

  elmHamburgers.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', onHamburgerClick));

})();
```

You could also replace the conditional: `if (overlay.isOpened === true) {...` 
with a one liner using `this.classList`

```
this.classList.toggle('is-opened-navi', overlay.isOpened)
```

Comment: Hey @ourmaninamsterdam! Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please see my answer that includes what you had since I can't make it work at the moment?

Comment: You have syntax errors. Remove the two lines (with the brackets) above `}());`.   On a separate note, it may be better to link to any code examples as jsfiddles within a comment rather than posting a new answer.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks so much! It is working very well now. Will be careful about your note regarding the comments next time. I am new to the forums, will improve my etiquette in time.