# querySelectorAll and event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-selectors, event-listener

I am currently trying to adapt [this demo](https://tympanus.net/Development/ShapeOverlays/index.html) for page transitions when you click on the links with the same class applied to them. Currently I have the following piece of code after @ourmaninamsterdam's recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820079/queryselectorall-and-multiple-elements-with-the-same-class) yet I can't seem to make it work. Do you have any recommendations on how I can get this to launch the transitions?

```js
<script>
// SVG Overlay Transition

// This will allow for delay for animation to play before next page load
$(".link-with-overlay").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function(url) { window.location = url }, 1700, this.href);
});
</script>


<script>
// These are the 'Easing' functions we will reference
const ease = {
  exponentialIn: (t) => {
    return t == 0.0 ? t : Math.pow(2.0, 10.0 * (t - 1.0));
  },
  exponentialOut: (t) => {
    return t == 1.0 ? t : 1.0 - Math.pow(2.0, -10.0 * t);
  },
  exponentialInOut: (t) => {
    return t == 0.0 || t == 1.0
      ? t
      : t < 0.5
        ? +0.5 * Math.pow(2.0, (20.0 * t) - 10.0)
        : -0.5 * Math.pow(2.0, 10.0 - (t * 20.0)) + 1.0;
  },
  sineOut: (t) => {
    const HALF_PI = 1.5707963267948966;
    return Math.sin(t * HALF_PI);
  },
  circularInOut: (t) => {
    return t < 0.5
        ? 0.5 * (1.0 - Math.sqrt(1.0 - 4.0 * t * t))
        : 0.5 * (Math.sqrt((3.0 - 2.0 * t) * (2.0 * t - 1.0)) + 1.0);
  },
  cubicIn: (t) => {
    return t * t * t;
  },
  cubicOut: (t) => {
    const f = t - 1.0;
    return f * f * f + 1.0;
  },
  cubicInOut: (t) => {
    return t < 0.5
      ? 4.0 * t * t * t
      : 0.5 * Math.pow(2.0 * t - 2.0, 3.0) + 1.0;
  },
  quadraticOut: (t) => {
    return -t * (t - 2.0);
  },
  quarticOut: (t) => {
    return Math.pow(t - 1.0, 3.0) * (1.0 - t) + 1.0;
  },
}
</script>

<script>
//Demo 6 Code
class ShapeOverlays {
  constructor(elm) {
    this.elm = elm;
    this.path = elm.querySelectorAll('path');
    this.numPoints = 10;
    this.duration = 900;
    this.delayPointsArray = [];
    this.delayPointsMax = 300;
    this.delayPerPath = 250;
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.isAnimating = false;
  }
  toggle() {
    this.isAnimating = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
      this.delayPointsArray[i] = Math.random() * this.delayPointsMax;
    }
    if (this.isOpened === false) {
      this.open();
    } else {
      this.close();
    }
  }
  open() {
    this.isOpened = true;
    this.elm.classList.add('is-opened');
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.renderLoop();
  }
  close() {
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.elm.classList.remove('is-opened');
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.renderLoop();
  }
  updatePath(time) {
    const points = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
      points[i] = (1 - ease.cubicInOut(Math.min(Math.max(time - this.delayPointsArray[i], 0) / this.duration, 1))) * 100
    }

    let str = '';
    str += (this.isOpened) ? `M 0 0 V ${points[0]}` : `M 0 ${points[0]}`;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints - 1; i++) {
      const p = (i + 1) / (this.numPoints - 1) * 100;
      const cp = p - (1 / (this.numPoints - 1) * 100) / 2;
      str += `C ${cp} ${points[i]} ${cp} ${points[i + 1]} ${p} ${points[i + 1]} `;
    }
    str += (this.isOpened) ? `V 100 H 0` : `V 0 H 0`;
    return str;
  }
  render() {
    if (this.isOpened) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
        this.path[i].setAttribute('d', this.updatePath(Date.now() - (this.timeStart + this.delayPerPath * i)));
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
        this.path[i].setAttribute('d', this.updatePath(Date.now() - (this.timeStart + this.delayPerPath * (this.path.length - i - 1))));
      }
    }
  }
  renderLoop() {
    this.render();
    if (Date.now() - this.timeStart < this.duration + this.delayPerPath * (this.path.length - 1) + this.delayPointsMax) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.renderLoop();
      });
    }
    else {
      this.isAnimating = false;
    }
  }
}

(function() {
  const elmHamburgers = document.querySelectorAll('.link-with-overlay');
  const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
  const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

  const onHamburgerClick = function() {
    if (overlay.isAnimating) {
      return false;
    }
    overlay.toggle();
    if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
      this.classList.add('is-opened-navi');

    } else {
      this.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
    }
  };

  // Iterates over all of the elements matched with class .link-with-overlay and 
  // adds an onclick event listener

  elmHamburgers.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', onHamburgerClick));
      
    }
  });
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not valid as you have too many closing brackets at the end of the file. The end of you code before the last closing `</script>` should look like this:

```js
      elmHamburgers.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', onHamburgerClick));
      
  })();

</script>
```